# Liferay Vaadin Session Timeout

Tags: session, timeout, liferay, vaadin

I have a problem that occurs after I sit idle, without touching the web browser, where vaadin throws its red communication problem error message after clicking anything in the vaadin app.

I run Liferay in apache/tomcat with Vaadin as a portlet.  The liferay and apache session timeouts are set to 8 hours.

I have tested by not touching the browser for 30 minutes.  After that time, when I click a button in the vaadin app, it throws the communication error message.

I have two application servers that sits behind a load balancer at rackspace.  I also have "sticky sessions" enabled...

Does vaadin perhaps have it's own timeout?

Can anybody help with this?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to my issue was yes, I need to set the portlet session timeout in the portlet web.xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the timeout value in web.xml along with heartbeatInterval and closeIdleSessions to manage session efficiently.

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html